# Is there a way to pass a string into the Average function?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet containing a column for the velocity of a vehicle, and I want to take specific ranges from that column (ranges where a turn occurs) and calculate the average speed of all turns combined.

I already have the turn ranges in two arrays, one for the turn starts and one for the turn ends. The code I wrote for this purpose looks like this:

```
Dim strTurnAvg As String
Dim k As Long
strTurnAvg = ""
For k = LBound(TurnStarts) To UBound(TurnStarts)
    If TurnStarts(k) <> TurnEnds(k) Then 'the code for detecting turns rarely messes up and takes the same cell as the start and end of a turn. This is used to ignore such instances
        If strTurnAvg = "" Then strTurnAvg = "Range(" & TurnStarts(k) & ":" & TurnEnds(k) & ").Value" Else strTurnAvg = strTurnAvg & ", Range(" & TurnStarts(k) & ":" & TurnEnds(k) & ").Value"
    End If
Next

Dim result As Double
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(strTurnAvg) '<- This results in a Run-time error '1004', Unable to get the Average property of the WorksheetFunction class
```

I tried manually putting the `strTurnAvg` result into an Average command, and everything worked perfectly fine, but when I try to pass it using the variable, it gives me the runtime error.
Is there a way to achieve this process in another way, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your entire approach is flawed I'm afraid. you can't build up some text that looks like VBA code and expect it to be interpreted as such at runtime. You should use the `Union` function to create a `Range` **object** that is passed to the `Average` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Dim TurnAvg As Range

Dim k As Long
For k = LBound(TurnStarts) To UBound(TurnStarts)
    If TurnStarts(k) <> TurnEnds(k) Then 'the code for detecting turns rarely messes up and takes the same cell as the start and end of a turn. This is used to ignore such instances
        If TurnAvg Is Nothing Then
            Set TurnAvg = Range(TurnStarts(k), TurnEnds(k))
        Else
            Set TurnAvg = Union(TurnAvg, Range(TurnStarts(k), TurnEnds(k)))
        End If
    End If
Next

Dim Result As Double
Result = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(TurnAvg)
```

It collects all the ranges using `Union` into `TurnAvg`. So you work with the actual ranges and the data in them. You cannot work with strings because you can only calculate with numbers but not with text. The `Average` functions needs numbers to calculate.

You might want to specify in which workbook/worksheet your ranges are like

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(TurnStarts(k), TurnEnds(k))
```

Otherwise VBA might pick the wrong workbook or wrong worksheet.